# How to read an unusual JSON file with VB.NET

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, file, json.net

I have an application in vb.net and I'm trying to read a .json file with Json.Net.  That's why I created the following class:

```
Public Class Example
    Public Property minecraft.net As String
    Public Property session.minecraft.net As String
    Public Property account.mojang.com As String
    Public Property auth.mojang.com As String
    Public Property skins.minecraft.net As String
    Public Property authserver.mojang.com As String
    Public Property sessionserver.mojang.com As String
    Public Property api.mojang.com As String
    Public Property textures.minecraft.net As String
End Class
```

But it has several problems, because the properties have dots "."

JSON format is as follows:

```
[{"minecraft.net":"green"},{"session.minecraft.net":"green"},{"account.mojang.com":"green"},{"auth.mojang.com":"green"},{"skins.minecraft.net":"green"},{"authserver.mojang.com":"green"},{"sessionserver.mojang.com":"green"},{"api.mojang.com":"green"},{"textures.minecraft.net":"green"}]
```

My question is, how do I create the class to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular JSON is a little unusual in that it is an array of objects where each object has only one key-value pair, and the keys vary from object to object.  Consequently, you will not be able to deserialize it into a strongly-typed class.  Instead, you can deserialize it into a `List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))` as shown below.

```
Dim json As String = "[{""minecraft.net"":""green""},{""session.minecraft.net"":""green""},{""account.mojang.com"":""green""},{""auth.mojang.com"":""green""},{""skins.minecraft.net"":""green""},{""authserver.mojang.com"":""green""},{""sessionserver.mojang.com"":""green""},{""api.mojang.com"":""green""},{""textures.minecraft.net"":""green""}]"

Dim list As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) = _
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)))(json)

For Each dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) In list
    Dim key As String = dict.Keys.First()
    Console.WriteLine(key & " = " & dict(key))
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RdcnJX